# Счетчик нажатия по анимации

Tags: javascript, функции, счетчики

Совсем недавно начал изучать JS, поэтому возникают сложности. Идея такая: пользователь заходит на страницу, где поочередно фигуры изменяют цвет, и необходимо успеть кликнуть на трансформирующуюся фигуру, чтобы получить балл.

Пока что получилось написать анимацию к смене цвета, а как сделал счетчик идей нет. Буду благодарен за ответы

```
let shape2 = document.getElementById('shape-2')
let shape3 = document.getElementById('shape-3')


let int;

function changeColorOne() {

  int = setInterval(function(){
  shape1.style.backgroundColor = '#70348C';
  setTimeout(function () {
     shape1.style.backgroundColor = '#00844B';
  }, 800);
}, 3600);
}
changeColorOne()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать счетчик лайков?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132510/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 1):

Привяжите к вашим shape'ам обработчики событий click (в случае необходимости погуглите про addEventListener и html-вский onclick). В функции-обработчике считайте клики (для этого заведите глобальную переменную и инкрементируйте ее с каждым кликом)

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрБ а как выглядит ваша анимация ?